# how to convert 1 Column that is struct<year:int,month:int,day:int> to a normalized yyyy/MM/dd date datatype format in scala

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

given I have a dataframe that includes two columns with the following struct, how can I convert the data in start_date and end_date to a yyyy/MM/dd format with a date datatype in sparkSQL (Scala).

Also end_date struct can also be null.

```
 |-- start_date: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- end_date: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: could please add your sample dataframe creation structure

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination (nesting) of [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_date-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) `&&` [format_string](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#format_string-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) `||` [concact_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#concat_ws-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-). Generally, you can achieve 90% of what you need with DataFrame [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

I'll provide more details once I wake up. It's late where I live...

UPDATE:

```
data.withColumn("start_date_as_date", 
  to_date(
    concat_ws("/", $"start_date.year", $"start_date.month", $"start_date.day"), 
    "yyyy/MM/dd")
  ).show
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|   start_date|     end_date|start_date_as_date|
+-------------+-------------+------------------+
|  [776, 9, 1]| [2019, 9, 2]|        0776-09-01|
|[2019, 9, 18]|[2019, 9, 19]|        2019-09-18|
|[2019, 10, 1]|[2019, 10, 2]|        2019-10-01|
+-------------+-------------+------------------+

... .printSchema
root
 |-- start_date: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- month: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- day: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- end_date: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- year: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- month: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- day: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- start_date_as_date: date (nullable = true)
```

Alternatively you could also use:

```
format_string("%02d/%02d/%02d", // this lets you get creative if you want!
    $"start_date.year", $"start_date.month", $"start_date.day")`
```

Answer (score 0):

> Spark 2.4+ you could use struct access (.) operator method here I am sharing code snippet.

```
scala> df.show
+--------------+--------------+
|    start_date|      end_date|
+--------------+--------------+
|[2019, 07, 11]|[2019, 08, 12]|
|[2019, 07, 14]|[2019, 08, 13]|
+--------------+--------------+

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- start_date: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- year: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: string (nullable = true)
 |-- end_date: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- year: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- month: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- day: string (nullable = true)

scala>var df1= df.withColumn("start_date",date_format(concat_ws("-",col("start_date.year"),col("start_date.month"),col("start_date.day")),"yyyy/MM/dd")).withColumn("end_date",date_format(concat_ws("-",col("end_date.year"),col("end_date.month"),col("end_date.day")),"yyyy/MM/dd"))

scala> df1.show
+----------+----------+
|start_date|  end_date|
+----------+----------+
|2019/07/11|2019/08/12|
|2019/07/14|2019/08/13|
+----------+----------+
```

let me know if you have any question related to the same.

Comment: your proposed solution when I printSchema gives me 

`df1.printSchema: 
root
 |-- start_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- end_date: string (nullable = true)`

I would like the data type to be `date` instead of `string`

Comment: @KurryF which format do you want as date like(yyyy-mm-dd) or (yyyy/mm/dd)